# Open a Word Document on the file list box with a command button

Tags: vb6

So I have a filelistbox along with dir and drivelistboxes.  I'm trying to open a word (.docx) file shown on the filelistbox when I press/click the "Open" Command Button that I created but it popups an:

> Error 5151 Words Was Unable to read this document. It may be corrupt.
>   Try one or more of the following"Open and repair the file." "Open the
>   file with the Text Recovery converter. (C:\Documents and Settings\JHON
>   Clarence\Desktop\ *.docx)"

Here is my code for the command button:

```
Private Sub cmdopen_Click()
    Dim nAns As Long
    Dim objFile As String
    Dim objpath As String
    Dim objname As String
    objpath = Dir1.Path & "\"
    objname = "*.docx"
    objFile = objpath & objname

    nAns = MsgBox("Please confirm to open file ' " & objFile & "'?'", vbQuestion & vbYesNo)
    If nAns = vbYes Then
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = True
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(objFile)
    End If
End Sub
```

The Debug highlights `Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(objFile)`
I have a hunch that the problem is about the `objname = "*.docx"` although I don't know how to open any word file (.docx) without typing any file name.

Comment: It is saying that `C:\Documents and Settings\JHON Clarence\Desktop*.docx` is not a Word document. It seems you want to delete all files with extension `docx` and to do that you'll have to enumerate them first. See `Dir` function (documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Dir-Function-1a1a4275-f92f-4ae4-8b87-41e4513bba2e))

Comment: What I'm trying to do is open the file with .docx extension not delete them.

Comment: Ah, was mislead by the comments. But you are supplying a `*.docx` as the name so you are trying to open **all** Word files in the path? If just one, why are you passing `*.docx` instead of the real filename?

Comment: What if I have different names for example __File1.docx__ and __File2.docx__ and I only want to open __File1.docx__ how do I open it without typing file1.docx on the `objname`?

Comment: If you want to let the user choose, then take a look at the [Application.FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx) object with the `msoFileDialogOpen` file dialog type. It'll allow the user to select the file and then you can use the filename to open it.

Comment: I'm also using Visual Basic 6.0.

Comment: Your tag was `vba` hence my link to the Office docs. My VB6 foo is very rusted (and I no longer have access to the IDE) so take a look at [this article](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/using-vb6-file-system-controls) as it describes how to use the file system controls to get filenames.